# .class selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working in a card game system that the player can select the card by clicking on it and then select the place to put it on. My problem is that when the player click on the target place, nothing happens.
This is my try: http://jsfiddle.net/5qMHz/
And this is my code:

```
function target() {
 $(".target").on("click", function() {
     $("#"+x).appendTo(this);
     console.log(x);     
 });
};
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What is "x" in $("#"+x)  ?

Comment: whats the `x` variable?

Comment: x is the variable defined on the top of the code. When the player clicks on a card, it sets the x to the card id.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/5qMHz/

Comment: @Rory McCrossan The target class is set via js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding with document, since you change the class during document ready and there was no element with the class `target` initially

```
  $(document).on("click",".target", function() {
   $("#" + x).appendTo(this);
   console.log(x);
  }
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5qMHz/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your practice of putting function references in to jQuery objects is rather odd. The problem however is that because the `.target` class is applied after DOM load you need to use a delegate selector. Try this:

```
var $card

$(".card").on("click", function () {
    $card = $(this);

    if ($(".myslot").length) {
        if ($(".myslot").is(':empty')) {
            $(".myslot:empty").addClass("target");
        } else {
            alert('No empty slots');
        }
    }
});

$('.field').on('click', ".target", function () {
    $card.appendTo(this);
    $card = $();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/5qMHz/6)

Comment: That looked weird to me too, but it's just setting the functions up as "ready" handlers, which would make sense outside the jsfiddle "load" handler wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are trying to bind the event handler, the elements don't have a class `target` yet. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`.

*(Technically the elements exist, but they are not (yet) addressable by the class `target`)*

You have three options to solve this:

1. Add the class to your HTML markup.
2. Bind the handler *after* you added the class to the elements.
3. Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

The first two don't really fit to your use case, since your are adding the class `target` in response to an other event and the number of elements with the class `target` changes over time. This is a good use case for event delegation though:

```
$('.field').on('click', '.target', function() {
   // ...
});
```